# Quiz app -next to display after Image result hides

Tags: ios, image

I am new to App Development, sorry if I am asking silly questions :(
I am developing a Quiz App. Whenever I give a right or wrong answer, an image appears with right or wrong answer result, however it stays for a few seconds, but after that - it does not continue with the next question. It just shows my background images with buttons. How can I set a code, that it goes straight to a new question, when the result image is gone.
I will be very thankful for your help.

I just want that after the Result-image closes, the quiz continues with the next question.

This is the code i have setup in Game.m file.

```
-(void)RightAnswer{

    ScoreNumber = ScoreNumber + 1;
    Score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", ScoreNumber];
    Answer1.hidden = YES;
    Answer2.hidden = YES;
    Answer3.hidden = YES;
    CategorySelected.hidden = NO;
    Next.hidden = NO;
    imageQuestion.hidden = YES;
    Results.hidden = NO;
    Results.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"right.png"]; [self performSelector:@selector(Results) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
    GameInProgress = YES;



}

-(void)WrongAnswer{

    LivesNumber = LivesNumber - 1;
    Lives.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", LivesNumber];
    Answer1.hidden = YES;
    Answer2.hidden = YES;
    Answer3.hidden = YES;
    imageQuestion.hidden = YES;
    CategorySelected.hidden = NO;
    Next.hidden = NO;
    Results.hidden = NO;
    Results.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"wrong.png"];[self performSelector:@selector(Results) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
    GameInProgress = YES;


    if(LivesNumber ==0) {
    Results.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gameover.png"];
    GameInProgress = NO;
    Exit.hidden = NO;

    }
```

Comment: where is your "Results" method? please paste it..

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? hide the image after 2 seconds, and then bring it back for the next question?

Comment: No, I just want that after the image close, the quiz continue with next question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i may be wrong here but I think you need an if to the else.
But I could be wrong.

```
if(LivesNumber ==0) {
    Results.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gameover.png"];
    GameInProgress = NO;
    Exit.hidden = NO;

}else{
    donextcard();    
}
```

if you want to know how to make that function we would need to see more of the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)Results{ // just change formate of answer.

    Results.hidden = YES;
}

-(IBAction)Answer1: (id) sender{

    if (Answer1Correct ==YES) {

        [self RightAnswer];

    }else{
        [self WrongAnswer];
    }
}

-(IBAction)Answer2: (id) sender{
    if (Answer2Correct ==YES) {
        [self RightAnswer];

    }
    else{
        [self WrongAnswer];

    }
}
-(IBAction)Answer3: (id) sender{
    if (Answer3Correct ==YES) {

        [self RightAnswer];

    }
    else{
        [self WrongAnswer];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)RightAnswer{

ScoreNumber = ScoreNumber + 1;
Score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", ScoreNumber];
Answer1.hidden = YES;
Answer2.hidden = YES;
Answer3.hidden = YES;
Answer1Correct ==YES;
CategorySelected.hidden = NO;
Next.hidden = NO;
imageQuestion.hidden = YES;
Results.hidden = NO;
Results.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"right.png"]; [self performSelector:@selector(Results) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
GameInProgress = YES;



 }
```

I think the issue is that you never set Answer1Correct to anything. so if you add Answer1Correct ==YES to the correct answer method and Answer1Correct ==NO to the wrong method then it should work

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I just want that the quiz should be continue with next question. I thought GameInProgress = YES; have worked but it does not